# Geeting 'chmod' error during React-Native template download on Ubuntu

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, ubuntu, npm

`Tried many solutions for this error. Even reinstalled Ubuntu 3 times but nothing changed. Everytime i try to create new react-native project it throws same error.`

```
✔ Downloading template
⠋ Copying template/home/shiva/.npm/_npx/64e95eb2d999e37b/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:265
        if (!chownErOk(er)) throw er
                            ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/home/shiva/Projects/my-app/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties'
    at Object.chmodSync (node:fs:1991:3)
    at Object.chmodSync (/home/shiva/.npm/_npx/64e95eb2d999e37b/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:263:21)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/home/shiva/.npm/_npx/64e95eb2d999e37b/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/copyFiles.js:83:19)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at emitCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:132:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'chmod',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/shiva/Projects/my-app/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties'
}
```

I am learning React-Native and also new to linux.

Tried to give full access to 'Projects' folder nothing works.

Comment: I had the same problem. I solved the issue by downgrading my Node version from 18.x to 16.x. I think latest React Native version (0.72) has some issues with Node versions 18.x or higher. My current config is: Node: 16.20.2, NPM: 8.19.4, Yarn: not installed, Ubuntu: 22.04.3

Answer (score 0):

Run command without the latest tag :)
Worked for me